# click on domain name modal should open like popup

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, yii2

in notification list I used sql query to display domain name but i want to each domain name when I click on that will open popup with there details.

this is header file---

```
 <!-- notification start -->
        <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Notification <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu short-dropdown-menu">

                         <li class=""> <a href="<?=Url::to(['domains/index']);?>">
                    <?php
                    $domains=Domains::find()
                      ->Where('expirydate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
                      ->andWhere(['or',
                                ['status'=> 'Active'],
                                ['status'=> 'Pending Transfer']
                            ])
                      ->orderBy(['expirydate' => SORT_ASC])
                      ->all();                                                                                    
              $domainList=ArrayHelper::map($domains,'id','domainname');
              foreach($domainList as $key => $value)
                     {
                        print '<br>'. $value .'<br>';
                     }
                    ?>       
                     </a></li>                                           
                      </ul>
                    </li>
        <!-- notification ends -->
```

now result is open like ---

[image]

when click on that domain name it have to display popup with details like below image-----

[image]

**UPDATE QUESTION:**

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Notification <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu short-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="">
                <a href="#modal-domaindetails" data-toggle="modal" onclick="getDomainDetails('2696')">

                <?php
                    $domains=Domains::find()
                            ->Where('expirydate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
                            ->andWhere([
                                          'or',
                                          ['status'=> 'Active'],
                                          ['status'=> 'Pending Transfer']
                                      ])
                            ->orderBy(['expirydate' => SORT_ASC])
                            ->all();                        


                    $domainList=ArrayHelper::map($domains,'did','domainname');
                        foreach($domainList as $key => $value) {
                            print '<br>'. $value .'<br>';
                        }
                ?>
                </a>  
            </li>                                           
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

see this now i am passing id 2696 but i want to take id as per domain name how is it possible

Comment: So what is your question? SO is not a code writing service. Show the relevant code and explain which part is giving your trouble.

Comment: create dropdown list  in header file when click on that open popup in notification list

Comment: Updated your question and edited my answer. I hope it's useful

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I have some view of it.

1. If you want to open a new popup modal, you have to create a modal popup, like that https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/
2. You put URL redirect to domain name as ">, it will be redirected to this link. You can not get any pop up here, except you want to open a new tab or new window in chrome. (with open new tab or new window you can search it on google)
3. In "li" and "a" tag

   `<li class="">
       <a href="your_url">
           ... your code php
           foreach($domainList as $key => $value) {
               print '<br>'. $value .'<br>';
           }
       </a>
   </li>`

you put an iterator, it will be rending a list but they have the same redirect to a URL

**UPDATE MY ANSWER**

Maybe I hope it will help you.

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Notification <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu short-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="">

                <?php
                    $domains=Domains::find()
                            ->Where('expirydate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
                            ->andWhere([
                                          'or',
                                          ['status'=> 'Active'],
                                          ['status'=> 'Pending Transfer']
                                      ])
                            ->orderBy(['expirydate' => SORT_ASC])
                            ->all();                        


                    $domainList=ArrayHelper::map($domains,'did','domainname');
                        foreach($domainList as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="getDomainDetails('<?= $key ?>')"><?= $value ?></a>
                <?php
                        }
                ?>

            </li>                                           
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

Added Modal popup

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>

    function getDomainDetails(domain_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'domains/index',
            method: 'GET', // or 'POST'
            data: { domain_id : domain_id }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $('#exampleModal').find('.modal-body').html(response); // append reponse html from server
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); // show modal
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: yes it is rendering a list but this is wrong i want to like select dropdown menu and when click on particular menu it wll open a popup.

Comment: What is your pop up, is it like modal popup of bootstrap?

Comment: <?php
echo $form->field($model, 'name[]')->dropDownList(
            ['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C']
    ); ?> ---- what is meaning of $model

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Using bootstrap modal

When click link, open modal

Request to server get data

Using jquery for render data again